# mootools textarea string

Tags: post, mootools, innerhtml

I want to send a Request with the content of a textarea but i get only a array instead of the wished string.

```
<textarea id="putup" name="textarea" cols="70" rows="15">http://www.example.com/?var=2EBR&n=1</textarea>

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
alert($('putup').value);
myRequest = new Request({
method: 'post',
url: 'build2.php',
}).post('var='+$('putup').value+'&uniquebutton='+$('uniquebutton').value);
});
```

my posts look like this:

```
Array ( [var] => http://www.example.com/?var=2EBR [n] => 1 [uniquebutton] => aqynnnisqopo )
```

how to get the real string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine except that your are trying to send a full url in your post without encoding it - which may create a problem if the url also contains parameters - like in your case it's &n=1 that is sending as post param key=>n value=>1 you need to use encodeURIComponent when u send urls and strings that might contains params chars so your param that hold this URL will include the entire URL and won't break it:

```
myRequest = new Request({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'build2.php',
}).post('var='+ window.encodeURIComponent($('putup').value)+'&uniquebutton='+$('uniquebutton').value);
```

and another little remark - in mootools u can use the get function of element to get any valid property of any element - so you can do $('pupup').get('value') but the classic way $('putup').value is perfectly fine of course.

Comment: You welcome. Id'e be happy if you set my answer as correct. thanks :)